# How to write binary files in R?

Tags: r, binary

I am trying to read multiple binary (365)files and do some calculations then read to another folder. I faced 2 problems:

First: The code below gives me an error:

```
Warning message: closing unused connection 3 (C:\PHD\Climate Data\Out\Temperature_1.dat

setwd("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Wind\\")
listfile<-dir()
for (i in c(1:365)) {
  conne <- file(`listfile[i], "rb")
  file<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=2,  n=360*720, signed=T)
  file<-file-273.15 #
  close(conne)
  to.write = file(paste("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Out\\Temperature_",i,".dat",sep=""),"wb")
  writeBin(file, to.write)
  close(to.write) 
}
```

Second:
As my files are `16bit,size=2`, I wanted to make sure that my output data have the same size.  So I just added `size=2` to  `writeBin(file, to.write, size=2)` but this gave an error:

```
Error in writeBin(file, to.write, size = 2) :   size 2 is unknown on this machine.
```

Any help on writing binary files properly is appreciated

Comment: A "Warning message" is not an error... R is just telling you it is closing a connection you don't seem to be using any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I can see you are trying to `writeBin()` a vector of `doubles` forcing each element to be of size 2.  That is not possible.

You may be able to `as.integer(file)` and try to write the resulting vector as elements of `size=2` but you'll have to try this.

Comment: IF this solved your problem could you tick it as the correct answer?