# How do I read multiple binary files in in different folders in R?

Tags: r

this code below is to read and loop thru multiple binary (365) files for one year in one folder. In fact I have many folders for many years, 365 files of year of 2000 in one folder, 365 files of year of 2001 in another folder and so on.

My question is how can I loop from one year to another (from one folder to another)?

```
setwd("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Wind\\")
listfile<-dir()
for (i in c(1:365)) {
  conne <- file(listfile[i], "rb")
  file<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=2,  n=360*720, signed=T)
  file<-file-273.15 #
  close(conne)
  to.write = file(paste("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Out\\Temperature_",i,".dat",sep=""),"wb")
  writeBin(file, to.write)
  close(to.write) 
}
```

Comment: To improve your odds of getting help, you should probably "accept" past answers that have helped you (like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10090849/903061)) by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Duplicate of your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032052/how-do-i-read-multiple-binary-files-in-r

Comment: Indeed, I've answered this question before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032052/how-do-i-read-multiple-binary-files-in-r

Comment: @Amen,  It sounds like the answers to your questions still aren't clear. I'd recommend reading a guide to getting started with R (something like http://www.luchsinger-mathematics.ch/Bashir.pdf) and then returning once you can clearly articulate what, specifically, you're having trouble with in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There a number of steps you need to take:

- You can use `list.files` to create a list of the files in the directory strucutre. Be sure to set `recursive` to `TRUE` in order to traverse the whole tree, and to set `full.names` to `TRUE` to get the names of the files including the subdirectory.
- Once you have read this list of files I would use `ldply` form the `plyr` package to get all the files.

Finally, an example in (untested pseudo) code that reads all the data looks something like:

```
list_of_files = list.files("datadir", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
dat = l_ply(list_of_files, function(fname) {
    dum_data = readBin(fname)
    writeBin(dum_data)
  })
```

`dat` will now be a `data.frame` which contains the data plus the associated time. Just replace the function with anything you like to get it working for your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However,It is a bit complex.I didn't clearly understand it.So now how do I insert the above loop which I wrote in this one which you have written.
 I did not really understand what you meant by this:(Just replace the function with anything you like to get it working for your example).

Comment: The bit of code you know have inside the for loop you can put into a function and use it in plyr. For more information on how plyr works in general, please read the paper that the author wrote at http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01

Comment: I changed the example to more closely match your problem

Comment: it seems that it is very advanced for my level. I do not really know how to use the code which you have provided. Anyway,thanks once again

Comment: If you read the paper I think things might become more clear. Good luck!